# Their eyes looks identical or their eyes look identical?

Tags: tense, present-tense, present-simple, present-participles

Their eyes looks identical or their eyes look identical? Which one would be grammatically correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Moon.  Asking "Which one is correct" is rarely a great question.  At least you should explain why this is difficult.  For example, would you say "The cats eat... " or "The cats eats..."  and why?  What rules do you know about verbs in English?

Answer (score 2):

The subject of the sentence is "eyes." (Whose eyes? *Their* eyes.) "Eyes" is a plural noun so you must conjugate the verb **to look** and find the third-person present plural conjugation:

> they look

So the correct sentence is

> Their eyes **look** identical.